# Stripe Terminal iOS - Resource not found when updating the reader software

Tags: ios, flutter, stripe-payments

I am currently in the process of developing a Flutter-based POS application that allows me to process credit card payments. Initially, I was using triPOS Mobile to connect my application to a credit card scanner. However, my curiosity led me to try out the Stripe Terminal iOS, which I was able to successfully integrate into my application about a month ago. Through Bluetooth connectivity, I was able to connect my BBPOS Chipper™ 3X BT credit card scanner to my application and carry out transactions seamlessly.

Due to another feature implementation, I stopped working on the project for a while and had not tested it since then. Unfortunately, I recently encountered an error when I tried to connect my scanner, which read as follows:

```
connectBluetoothReader failed: Error Domain=com.stripe-terminal Code=3800 "Updating the reader software failed. Please try again. Resource not found (3410)" UserInfo={com.stripe-terminal:ReaderMessage=Resource not found (3410), NSLocalizedDescription=Updating the reader software failed. Please try again. Resource not found (3410), com.stripe-terminal:Message=Updating the reader software failed. Please try again. Resource not found (3410)}
```

Despite my efforts to resolve the issue by deleting and adding the most up-to-date version of StripeTerminal.xcframework in my Flutter/iOS project, the error persists. Additionally, I attempted to run the Stripe Terminal iOS example app with the Heroku backend, which previously worked for me, but to no avail.

At this point, I am uncertain of what may have caused the error and how to resolve it. If anyone else has encountered this error or has any insight, please share your thoughts.

Answer (score 0):

The 3X BT is not a [reader that Stripe supports](https://stripe.com/docs/terminal/payments/setup-reader). Additionally, you can only use [readers obtained from Stripe directly](https://support.stripe.com/questions/stripe-terminal-support-for-different-card-readers).

If you want to integrate Stripe Terminal payments, you should review the [docs](https://stripe.com/docs/terminal) and order a reader from Stripe (or use Tap to Pay). Additionally, Stripe's SDKs do not officially support Flutter. Problems would need to be reproduced using the native SDKs directly to ensure the issue does not lie with the Flutter bridge.